# PHP MYSQLI Prepared Count Query

Tags: php, mysqli, count

I am trying to translate the mysqli query that works perfectly into  prepared statements, it does not seem to run and returns a http 500 error. Is this the way it should be done?

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx", "xxx");

$sel_query = "SELECT 
S1, B1
COUNT(IF(S1 = ?, 1, NULL)) 'Accepted',
COUNT(IF(S1 = ?, 1, NULL)) 'Rejected',
COUNT(IF(S1 = ?, 1, NULL)) 'Under_Review' FROM Enrol";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sel_query);     

$Accepted="Accepted";
$Rejected="Rejected";
$Under_Review="Under Review";

    
$stmt->bind_param("sss",$Accepted, $Rejected, $Under_Review);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result(); // get the mysqli result
  
if($result->num_rows === 0) exit('No records found!');
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  ?>


 <tr>
    
    <td><?php echo $row["Accepted"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Rejected"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Under_Review"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Show us the code where you prepare it.

Comment: $sel_query = "SELECT 
S1, B1
COUNT(IF(S1 = ?, 1, NULL)) 'Accepted',
COUNT(IF(S1 = ?, 1, NULL)) 'Rejected',
COUNT(IF(S1 = ?, 1, NULL)) 'Under_Review' FROM Enrol";




$stmt->bind_param("sss",$Accepted, $Rejected, $Under_Review);

Comment: Where do you call the `prepare` method?

Comment: $stmt = $conn->prepare($sel_query);

Comment: [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: I have the error checking turned on, despite that it is going to error 500

Comment: Check error logs. Both PHP and apache/nginx